# What should be the file permissions in macOS?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, macos

The question is regarding macOS but I believe it belongs in this forum because macOS works like UNIX under the hood. So here goes.

When installing certain software packages on macOS, the package installation instruction will say that one does not need sudo for installing the package.
I have encountered permission errors when installing these packages without sudo (homebrew and cordova for example).

The error usually describes the file/folder for which the permission failed. (In the past I have simply used sudo to force install (I know, not a nice thing to do, but one makes mistakes)).

I have several questions in this regard.

- **How do I find out what the permissions for the file/folder should be for the installation to work without sudo?**

  It is possible that something was installed/removed in the past that caused a change in file/folder permission that is now causing this error.
- **Is there a way to know which files/folders have the wrong permissions? or for which the permissions, by default, are different?**
- **Is there some way to set these permissions back to how they should be?**
- **Is there software out there that can scan my drive and identify this problem and fix it?**

Comment: Homebrew _definitely_ does not need root permissions for most packages! What package are you installing?  The fact that you need to resort to using `sudo` implies that you have changed the default permissions on directories under `/usr/local`.